# DataTable not showing up C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have this datatable, which will display the values from the database.

```
    private void CreateTable() {
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ScheduleID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
    ... }
```

I'm using this code, and there are no errors but I don't know why the values aren't showing up. Any help? Thanks.

```
dgvSchedule.DataSource = new DataView(dt, "Username = '" + lblUsername.Text + "' and Subject = '" + cbxSubject.Text + "'", "Subject", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Comment: Make sure your select criteria is correct

Comment: You are creating the columns, but it seems that you are not populating the datatable with rows.

Comment: You created a DataTable in code with the columns, but how did it get populated with data?

Comment: @LarsTech No I used **dgvSchedule.DataSource = dsSched.Tables["Schedules"];**

Comment: @Cant Handle Me Babe if dt is your datatable, then
`var row = dt.NewRow();
row["ScheduleID"] = 5;
row["Username"] = "kerzek";`
etc
dt.rows.add(row);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post my answer here, for readability.

If dt is your datatable, then you can do something like this

```
var row = dt.NewRow(); 
row["ScheduleID"] = 5; 
row["Username"] = "kerzek";
dt.rows.add(row);
```

Comment: Thanks. But now whenever I press the button, another row is added, then another. What do i do? I'm using a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

agreeing with the other comments, and the constructor for the dataview appears incorrect.

[DataView Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.dataview.aspx), but that might be dependent upon the framework your using